# Are all gems used required in the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm pretty new to Ruby and have been reading up about Gemfiles and the like.  Recently we were bitten by this bug in one of our programs:

https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/440

However, in looking through the Gemfile in question, the `ffi` gem wasn't listed.  It is now, pinned to a prior (working) version for the OS in question.

But I'm wondering how things worked before if it wasn't in the Gemfile to start?  Are there some 'core' gems out there that come along for the ride, with no need to put them in a Gemfile?

Comment: chances are `ffi` was a dependency of one of the gems you are using. This dependency probably did not specify the gem version and thus if you update bundler it will try and use the newest version but it is difficult to tell without knowing what gems you are using

Comment: Thank you.  Turns out it's just as you and @osman said, one of our gems required it, and we had nothing for it in Gemfile.lock

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gems have dependencies and so they get installed as well. You can check your Gemfile.lock to see exactly which gems are installed.